# Failed to use sp_session_relogin (libspotify)

Tags: authentication, spotify

my question is quite simple : how sp_session_relogin is working ?

Here is how I try to use it.

```
bool login(const char* login, const char* password, bool remember)
{
    if (remember) {
        sp_error err = sp_session_relogin(_session);
        if (err==SP_ERROR_OK) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!login||!password) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    sp_session_login(_session, login, password, remember, NULL);
    return true;
}
```

and I my application I first call

```
login(0,0,true);
```

and if it returns false I recall it like this

```
login(username,password,true);
```

(username and password are retrieved from a UI).
then if I quite the application and relaunched it the first call to login continue to return false.

**Edited after the answer from iKenndac**

I was calling sp_session_logout() but I was not waiting for the logout callback being called. I had it but it is not better.
Here is how my application is ending

```
if (_session) {
    if (_loggedin) {
        char buffer[1024];
        int ret = sp_session_remembered_user(_session,buffer,sizeof(buffer)); 
        if (ret>0) {
            printf("remembered user: %s\n",buffer);
        }
        sp_session_logout(_session);
        int msTilNext = 0;
        while(_loggedin) {
            sp_session_process_events(_session, &msTilNext);
        }
    }

    sp_session_release(_session);
    _session = 0;
}
```

sp_session_remembered_user correctly return my username. After logout I am waiting for the logout callback being called processing event with sp_session_process_events. When logout callback is called, _loggedin became false so the loop end. I release the session. And quite the application.

Do you see another mistake or missing stuff ? Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you quit your application, make sure you call `sp_session_logout()` and wait until the logout completion callback is fired before allowing the application to terminate. Otherwise you're likely to get an incomplete cache which will cause `sp_session_relogin()` to fail.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it seems I still missed something. I have updated my question to explain how I loggout and quit my application.

Comment: I found your Viva spotify player ... I'll look at it to try to understand what I am missing but at this time I did not found. Not sure if I missing at the beginning (when I try to relogin) or at the end (when I am logout).

Comment: I find my problem : it is just that the settings folder cannot be created as it contains no existing directory. I create the path and all its directories and now it is ok. Thanks again iKenndac.